# Using Async and Promises that are all rejected leads to async never completing

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm using `async` and `promise` to run a seeding script but in the case where all promses are `reject`ed the script never completes.

As it's a seeding script it's set up to not seed models that alredy have data.

Here's (abridged) my code

Any idea what I've missed?

```
seed = function(collectionName, data) {
  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    var collection = collections[collectionName];
    collection.find().exec(function(err, found) {
      if (found.length > 0) {
        console.log("There are", found.length, collectionName, "records in the database already.");
        reject();
      } else {
        collection.createEach(data, function(err, models) {
          if (err || _.isUndefined(models)) {
            console.log("Could not create", collectionName, "collection!");
            reject();
          } else {
            collection.find().exec(function(err, found) {
              fulfill(found);
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
};

run = function(models, done) {
  async.each(models, function(modelName, next) {
    seed(modelName, modelData[modelName]).then(function(codes) {
      console.log("Seeded", codes.length, modelName, "records.");
      next();
    }, function(err){
      console.log("Seeding of", modelName, "failed", err.stack);
      done(err);
    });
  }, done);
};

run(["widget", "thingo", "dooverlackey"], function(err){
  if (err) console.error("Completed with errors", err);
  else console.log("Completed without errors");
  process.exit();
});
```

Comment: Further to this, if i pass in the error message to `reject("my error")` then the whole lot stops at the first error which is not what I want either.  I just want it to skip any models that already have data.

Comment: Promises already provide asynchronous aggregation and structuring. There is really no reason to use the async module here. You can simply `.then` chain them without async in a for loop.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin - that's a good point, but using `async` I can just add another model to my array and voila. Perhaps getting rid of the Promise structure instead would simplify things instead.

Comment: You can .then with promises and get the same viola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, if you reject on a call to `seed()`, then your code will go to the reject handler in your `.then()` where you call `done()`.  So, your own structure has told it to stop processing if it gets a rejection in this code:

```
seed(modelName, modelData[modelName]).then(function(codes) {
  console.log("Seeded", codes.length, modelName, "records.");
  next();
}, function(err){
  console.log("Seeding of", modelName, "failed", err.stack);
  // upon fail from seed, stop processing
  done(err);
});
```

You can either change your reject handler (the second callback passed to `.then()`) so that it continues processing or you can change `seed()` to only reject if there is a serious error that you cannot continue from.

Though there are many different ways to use promises, it's probably more conventional to reserve the reject for a serious failure that you cannot continue from which would mean changing your `seed()` function to only `reject()` if there's a serious error.  When it merely finds that it doesn't have anything to do because the work has already been done, it would just `resolve()` and let the whole process continue.